# c# httpWebrequest with proxy works but not curl

Tags: c#, php, security, curl

I can make a request through a corporate proxy with authentication using c# and httpWebrequest. I could then get the proxy and port used.

Then I tried to use it with curl, wget and rebol and all failed.

For example after creating environment variable http-proxy containing proxy ip and port, I type this command in cmd prompt:

```
curl --proxy-user login:password google.com
```

it answers

```
(6) could not resolve host:google.com
```

For what reason does http request works for c# and not for others ?

Comment: `curl --proxy-user login:password http://google.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried syntax similar to:

```
curl -U user:passwd -x proxy:port http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable for a http proxy should be 'http_proxy' (minus the quotes). Note the lower case letters and underscore.

Comment: sorry mistypo I used http_proxy

Comment: you might want to use -v to get more information about exactly what curl does