# Is it possible to make any exe resident in memory?

Tags: windows, shell

For example let's say I need to call curl.exe 1000 times in a row from rebol (see [c# httpWebrequest with proxy works but not curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428182/c-httpwebrequest-with-proxy-works-but-not-curl) ) to avoid reloading curl from disk each time, is there a way to make it stay in memory ? I don't think making a windows service does that.

Answer (score 1):

No; Windows should be doing that automatically.